# R - group data in dataframe by two columns and rearrange into new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe foo:

```
   A  B  C
1  x  m  2
2  x  n  3
3  x  o  11
4  y  m  5
5  y  o  8
```

Edit: thanks to @akrun for reminding me, I add the code to produce this df:

```
foo <- structure(list(A = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y"), 
       B = c("m", "n", "o", "m", "o"), C = c(2L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 8L)), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

and from it I want to create a new data frame, with the values in A as row names, the values in B as column names, and as entries the values in C, like so:

```
   m  n  o
x  2  3  11
y  5  NA 8
```

So far I found the aggregate() function

```
aggregate(.~A, foo, FUN=toString)
```

which gives me sth like this (it converts the letters in B to numbers though) and is not what I need here:

```
   A  B      C
1  x  1,2,3  2,3,11
2  y  1,3    5,8
```

I found answers on SO suggesting the dplyr package and group_by for similar problems, but I couldn't wrap my head around how to adapt this to my problem. Sorry if I overlooked something, thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to pursue a `tidyverse` solution, you can use `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`.

**Edit**: Added `column_to_rownames` to move column A to row names.

```
library(tidyverse)

foo %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = A, names_from = B, values_from = C) %>%
  column_to_rownames("A")
```

**Output**

```
  m  n  o
x 2  3 11
y 5 NA  8
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! It places the names of A into the first column and does not set them as row names, but this is easily fixed in a second step.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(C ~ A + B, df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y"), B = c("m", "n", 
"o", "m", "o"), C = c(2L, 3L, 11L, 5L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also a nice solution if you don't want to use tidyverse. It produces however a xtabs table.

> foo1 <- xtabs(C ~ A + B, foo)
> class(foo1)
[1] "xtabs" "table"

Comment: And thanks for adding the code to produce my little example, I will include it into my original post!